# How can an SSO if be passed to a federated service?

Tags: .net, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, pingfederate

Trying to use MSAL username password flow to acquire a token from a federated service token endpoint (Ping Federate) but getting an auth error 1003. I think it might be because PF is expecting an SSO id that is not the username that MSAL passed in. Is there a way to set the SSO Id in MSAL?

Answer (score 0):

You MAY be able to use similar approach to that used by ADAL to acquire token for federated users using the AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new UserCredential()) - in your case you would use new UserPasswordCredential class instead of UserCredential. Behind the scenes ADAL will use WS-Trust to acquire a SAML token from ADFS and then OAuth2 Extension Flow to exchange it for a JWT.